# POSIXct - NA Value

Tags: r, xts, na, posixct

I am trying to create a xts object (1 year, hourly data). The problem is, R does not let me use order.by, since there seems to be a random NA value in the vector I want to use to order.

```
    > x = read.csv(choose.files(), header=TRUE, sep=";")
    > x = as.POSIXct(Data_neu$Date, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
    > str(x)
     POSIXct[1:8760], format: "2016-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 01:00:00"
    > which(is.na(x))
    [1] 2067
```

To answer one of the questions that might come up - no the value was not NA before formatting. It was just as all the other values whithin the vector. More precisely it looked like this: 27.03.2016 02:00.

Why does exactly **this** value converts to NA when formating it? I can not find any logical explanation (nor solution).

Thanks in advance! I appreciate any kind of help or comment..

Comment: Probably daylight saving.

Comment: Alright, makes sense, thanks - do you know how to adress this (in this case)?

Comment: I would suggest that you start by having a look at previous posts on SO. This topic has been [addressed quite a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+daylight+saving). Cheers.

Comment: Yup, did so and found a proper solution. Thanks!